# Wave Labs Heroku App Issue

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics-cloud

After Summer 16 release last week i am facing this issue.
It looks like, the version of existing wave dashboards is automatically increased to 37, Whereas the wavelabs heroku app works on 36.0 only. 
So when i use json editor, it gives an error **Dashboard state conversion failed: Cannot convert from a 37.0**. 
I found the same type of error on workbench also. 
Can anyone suggest, how to change the version of wave dashboard from 37 to 36.
I tried using ant tool, but there is no meta xml file for a wave dashboard file. And the .wapp file also doesn't have version tag.
Is there any other way to do this?